# How to make a Legend of MatPlotLib patch patterns or add them to a preexisting Legend

Tags: matplotlib, legend

How does one make a legend for patch patterns used on a graph or add information on the patch patterns to a preexisting legend without affecting information already present on the legend?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the patch include the kwarg `label` , ex

```
## bunch of code
ax.add_patch(mpl.patches.Rectangle(...,label='fail'))
## bunch of code
ax.plot(...,label='some line')
## bunch of code
ax.legend()
```

and it will be automaigically added to your legend.  And entry will be added for each artist that you have added a label to.

If you make your legend via `legend(hands,labs)`, just add the patch object to the `hands` list as you would a `Line2D` object.  `legend` really works on `artists` which both `patch` and `Line2D` are derived from.