# Adding proxy legend handles to an existing legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

In the [Matplotlib Legend Guide documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles) there is an example of how to create proxy artists specifically for the legend.

In the example, a patch is created specifically for display in the legend. The patch object is then passed to the legend handle (if I am interpreting the example correctly).

My question is, what happens if you have already performed multiple plot instances so that there is heaps of stuff in:

```
plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
```

and you want to do:

```
plt.legend()
```

and then subsequently add proxy artists/stuff to the legend that isn't in the figure or axes.

A very similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128987/how-to-make-a-legend-of-matplotlib-patch-patterns-or-add-them-to-a-preexisting-l), with one answer that was never marked as correct, but seems like what I am looking for. Unfortunately, as a low reputation user I couldn't comment in the existing question. The answer from **tacaswell** implies it can be done, but I cannot interpret this step:

> "just add the patch object to the handles list as you would a Line2D
>   object"

I have some example code I could put up to show my specific case, but was unsure if it would help someone answer or just make the question too specific and difficult to interpret.

Any help or advice appreciated.

Comment: Hi @jcb it seems I can't message you otherwise, but I googled your (removed) post on Stack Hardware about the problem with the unnlink USB switcher. I have the exact same problem exact same motherboard. But I can't seem to use front panel USB, the only method that work is adding another USB hub in between (I don't have an extension as you). Did you manage to fix it? - my email is diogo.kamioka at the most common email provider out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> "just add the patch object to the handles list as you would a Line2D object"

is to be taken literally. Suppose you have created a `red_patch`, and you have a list of handles `handles`, you add (`+`) that `red_patch` to the `handles`

```
plt.legend(handles=handles + [red_patch])
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot([0,1],[i,i+1], label=f"Label {i}")

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')


handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
# "just add the patch object to the handles list as you would a Line2D object"
plt.legend(handles=handles + [red_patch])

plt.show()
```

[image]